# data.table confusion using rollends argument of rolling join

Tags: r, data.table

I'm having some trouble understanding data.table's `rollends` argument when doing a rolling join.

The docs for reference:

> A logical vector length 2 (a single logical is recycled) indicating
>   whether values falling before the first value or after the last value
>   for a group should be rolled as well.
>
> - If rollends[2]=TRUE, it will
>     roll the last value forward. TRUE by default for LOCF and FALSE for
>     NOCB rolls.
> - If rollends[1]=TRUE, it will roll the first value
>     backward. TRUE by default for NOCB and FALSE for LOCF rolls.

---

Now a confusing example. Here, I build a table of commercials and two different tables of sales.

```
# commercials
commercials<-data.table(commercialID=c("C1","C2","C3","C4"), commercialDate=as.Date(c("2014-1-1","2014-4-1","2014-7-1","2014-9-15")))
commercials[, rollDate:=commercialDate] #Add a column, rollDate equal to commercialDate
setkey(commercials, "rollDate")

commercials
   commercialID commercialDate   rollDate
1:           C1     2014-01-01 2014-01-01
2:           C2     2014-04-01 2014-04-01
3:           C3     2014-07-01 2014-07-01
4:           C4     2014-09-15 2014-09-15


# sales1 (A single sale before all commercials)
sales1 <- data.table(saleID=c("S0"), saleDate=as.Date(c("2010-12-31")))
sales1[, rollDate:=saleDate]
setkey(sales1, "rollDate")

sales1
saleID   saleDate   rollDate
1:     S0 2010-12-31 2010-12-31


# sales2 (A sale before all commercials and a sale after commercial1)
sales2 <- data.table(saleID=c("S0", "S1"), saleDate=as.Date(c("2010-12-31", "2014-2-1")))
sales2[, rollDate:=saleDate]
setkey(sales2, "rollDate")

sales2
saleID   saleDate   rollDate
1:     S0 2010-12-31 2010-12-31
2:     S1 2014-02-01 2014-02-01
```

Now for some rolling joins

```
sales1[commercials, roll=TRUE, rollends=c(TRUE, FALSE)]
   saleID saleDate   rollDate commercialID commercialDate
1:     NA     <NA> 2014-01-01           C1     2014-01-01
2:     NA     <NA> 2014-04-01           C2     2014-04-01
3:     NA     <NA> 2014-07-01           C3     2014-07-01
4:     NA     <NA> 2014-09-15           C4     2014-09-15

sales2[commercials, roll=TRUE, rollends=c(TRUE, FALSE)]
   saleID   saleDate   rollDate commercialID commercialDate
1:     S0 2010-12-31 2014-01-01           C1     2014-01-01
2:     NA       <NA> 2014-04-01           C2     2014-04-01
3:     NA       <NA> 2014-07-01           C3     2014-07-01
4:     NA       <NA> 2014-09-15           C4     2014-09-15
```

### Questions

1. Why does sale S0 get mapped to C1 in the second join but not the first?
2. A better/different explanation of what `rollends` is doing.

Oh, and I'm currently using the development version, 1.9.7

Comment: An article from yesterday can help on Q2: [Understanding data.table Rolling Joins](http://r-norberg.blogspot.co.uk/2016/06/understanding-datatable-rolling-joins.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case,

```
sales1[commercials, roll=TRUE, rollends=c(TRUE, FALSE)]
```

`2014-01-01` row in `commercials` falls *after* `2010-12-31`. The prevailing value has to be carried forward. But it also falls on the *end*, i.e., after `sales1`, and you've provided `rollends[2] = FALSE`. So it doesn't get rolled forward.

In the second case,

```
sales2[commercials, roll=TRUE, rollends=c(TRUE, FALSE)]
```

`2014-01-01` row in `commercials` falls *in between* `2010-12-31` and `2014-02-01`. There's no effect of `rollends` for this row since it doesn't fall on either end. So the last value gets rolled forward.

All other values fall outside of `sales2`. So `rollends` argument comes into play. And `rollends[2] = FALSE]` means prevailing values won't be rolled forwards.

Comment: Thanks Arun. This helped a lot, but I still needed to do a little futzing on my own to understand what was happening.  I think the documentation could use a little tweaking to make things clearer.  I'd probably change the bullets to "If rollends[1]=TRUE, the first value in x will roll backwards, else it will be stationary. FALSE by default for LOCF and TRUE for NOCB rolls" and "If rollends[2]=TRUE, the last value in x will roll forward, else it will be stationary. TRUE by default for LOCF and FALSE for NOCB rolls."  I'll try to make a PR on github sometime soon.  Thanks again!

Comment: What do you find hard in this line? "A logical vector length 2 (a single logical is recycled) indicating whether values falling before the first value or after the last value for a group should be rolled as well." If you follow this, it should be clear that a value can fall before the beginning of a group or after the end of a group (in addition to falling within), and each index controls how they should be treated. I think it's quite clear. I think working out more examples would help grasp it better.

Comment: Consider this statement: "If rollends[2]=TRUE, it will roll the last value forward."  1) What does "the last value" mean?  Values in table x or values in table i?  2) What happens if rollends[2]=FALSE?  Do values roll backwards or remain stationary?  I made the wrong assumptions which cause my confusion.  These statements could be improved IMO.  (Regardless of this minor thing, data.table is AWESOME and thanks for all your work on it, Arun!)